# Schengen visa category required for job interview

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, austria

I am travelling to Austria for a job interview (for 2 days). Which type of visa should I apply for?

My home country is India and the visit to Austria will be be sponsored by the inviting company. The company will also provide me with an invitation letter.

Answer (score 9):

I am posting the answer to my question, this is same for all non-EU persons, who wants to visit Europe for a scheduled interview.

VISA type required was **Type C** with purpose as **Others (Visiting a company for an interview)**

Chances of getting visa will improve if: -

1. If you have an invitation letter for an interview, correctly stating your **visit
   dates** or **number of days** they required you for an interview. This is a must for this visa.
2. If they are sponsoring your trip. This pretty much granted the visa.
3. If you are having a full time job in your home country, to prove that you
   have strong ties to your home country.

You can certainly skip giving them leave approvals from your employer, by stating the reason in cover letter. Obviously, no employer would give you a leave for giving interview.

Good luck !!

Comment: "Obviously, no employer would give you a leave for giving interview." I can imagine several reasons why that might not be the case.

Comment: Yes, but we have to consider the context the of interview. right ?

Comment: @hsg just wondering what did you specify the reason for not providing leave approvals from your employer in a cover letter

Comment: @Vinay Reason can be because of job interview. But attaching sponsorship letter and hotel flight bookings is a must here.

Comment: How long does it take to get that visa on average?

Answer (score 4):

It's a short-stay (type C) visa that you want.

If the form asks for the purpose, select business.

Comment: "If the form asks for the purpose": it does.